# Transit through Heathrow on separate tickets?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas, lhr

I will be transiting through Heathrow coming from Frankfurt, connecting to Dubai soon.
Those flights are on seperate tickets with hours of connecting times inbetween.
I will only be carrying hand luggage with me and will have all my boarding passes on my phone.

Do I need to clear customs / go through immigration or can I just connect without leaving the passengers-only zone?
Would appreciate your help!

Greetings,
Robin

Comment: Check https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/airport-maps/travel-between-terminals  It depends on the exact flight (so the arriving and departing terminals).

Comment: Note that even if you manage to do it airside, the first airline will in most cases consider that your final destination is London, and won't let you board the first flight unless you meet all entry requirements for the UK (passport or visa, COVID restrictions, locator form...).

Comment: If you must pass UK Immigration and Customs to get to your connecting flight, then you have to "enter" the UK. That, in turn, and depending on your citizenship and itinerary, may require a UK transit visa. Check [this UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) for more information.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: transit visa is independent of passing UK immigration. Some airlines check transit visa at embarkation. API [Advanced Passenger Information] (which it is required for flight to UK) may give hints to immigration about your lack of transit visa.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Not independent, but clearly dependent: if a transit traveler needs a UK transit visa (of either type) and doesn't have it, then the traveler will not be able to pass UK Immigration, and will not be able to catch the second leg flight. I agree, however, that boarding is likely to be denied at the first leg flight departure.